# Change PowerShell execution mode to -NonInteractive within Script?

Tags: powershell

To avoid interaction or stops in script execution for input in PowerShell has to be run in Non Interactive mode. Such as:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive
```

I would like to change this execution mode in script 'runtime' without having to restart or use another PowerShell console. Or maybe a way to force the 'non-interaction'.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so, the `NonInteractive` switch affects a bunch of settings that are only touched at startup

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hide the console during runtime, and show the console again when you are done.

```
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'

function Show-Console {
   $consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
  #5 show
 [Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 5)
}

function Hide-Console {
    $consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
  #0 hide
 [Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 0)
}
```

Comment: At the moment I need to maintain certain values which are stored in the current console session, so opening another console would clean these. Thanks for the input.